# How to write click event for table's first column

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular8

I am trying to write a click event for the table's first column. If I click the first column ID I want to get that value in an alert box. I tried, but it's not working. Rows is not taking in Angular 7 and 8.

Do not use element reference like #tableId. Please use table id.

app.component.html:

```
  <table id="tableId">
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12346</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12347</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12348</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12349</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12310</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const table = <HTMLTableElement> document.getElementById('tableId');
    for (let row of table.rows) {
      const firstCell = row.childNodes.item(0);
      firstCell.addEventListener('click', () => alert(firstCell.textContent));      
      (<HTMLElement> firstCell).setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer;');
    }
  }
```

Comment: you want to get only first or onclick of any row

Comment: In my opinion, this code works fine for Angular 8: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mypspz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the reference variable for your table `#tableId`in html.

Reference tableId variable inside Component

```
@ViewChild("tableId") table: ElementRef;
```

Attach the click event for all your first cells

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
     let tblElement = this.table.nativeElement;
      for (let row of tblElement.rows) {
      const firstCell = row.childNodes.item(0);
      firstCell.addEventListener('click', () => alert(firstCell.textContent));      
      (<HTMLElement> firstCell).setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer;');
    }
  }
```

Working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elementref-example-jpj5a7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick event for tr (so that if user clicks anywhere in the table, you will get the respective row id) and get the children.

```js
function test(event){
  console.log($(event).find('td').eq(0).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId">
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr onclick = "test(this)">
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick = "test(this)">
    <td>12346</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick = "test(this)">
    <td>12347</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```